# Generating function for the Josephus Problem?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, generating-functions

According to the [Wikpedia article on the Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), the general solution is by dynamic programming. However, since there seems to be an explicit recurrence rule for the problem, should there not be a generating function in terms of *n* and *k*, where *n* is the number of people and *k* is the decimation interval, that gives a solution by direct calculation?

Comment: For $k=2$, [OEIS A006257](https://oeis.org/A006257) gives a generating function from Ralf Stephan which is something like $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{2}{1-x} \left( \frac{3x-1}{2-2x} - \sum_{m \ge 1} 2^{m-1}x^{2^m} \right)$ and looking at [OEIS A198788](https://oeis.org/A198788) I doubt it gets simpler for larger $k$